# Check for order confirmation

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, shopping-cart, wkwebview

I'm creating an iOS app that allows users to purchases items. We use a WKWebView to allow the user to purchase items off 3rd party websites.

How would I go about tracking if a purchase went fully though via the WKWebView?

I've toyed with the idea of scraping the WKWebView of HTML, storing it in a string and doing a simple `.contains`. This would look for specific strings like "order confirmation". Storing all strings in a table would end up being quite intensive as we have multiple providers and multiple permutations on the strings.

Any recommendations on how to approach this issue?